# Attempting to loop through a list of direct download links; first file downloads but second gets stuck at 0 bytes and never finishes (C#)

Tags: c#, download, webclient

I'm attempting to run through a list of direct download links using the code below. The code runs and downloads the first file just fine, as it moves to the second file (second link in the list), it correctly creates the new file and initiates download, but stops at 0 bytes and does not continue.

I've attempted to run through with breakpoints and similar, and all data looks correct. I've moreover confirmed it is possible to download multiple files in rapid succession without any issues from the website in question.

Any help, feedback or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
foreach (string s in links)
        {
            using (WebClient w = new WebClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Attempting to download " + s);
                    w.OpenRead(s);

                    string content = w.ResponseHeaders["Content-Disposition"];
                    string filename = new ContentDisposition(content).FileName;

                    w.DownloadFile(new Uri(s), _directory + filename);
                    Console.WriteLine("Downloaded " + filename);
                }
                catch(WebException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

Furthermore, downloading directly, i.e. by using the below, works fine.

```
using (WebClient w = new WebClient())
        {
            w.DownloadFile(new Uri(downloadLinks[0]), _directory + "test");
            w.DownloadFile(new Uri(downloadLinks[1]), _directory + "test1");
            w.DownloadFile(new Uri(downloadLinks[2]), _directory + "test2");
            w.DownloadFile(new Uri(downloadLinks[3]), _directory + "test3");
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does anything happen if you move `WebClient` *outside* of your `foreach` loop?

Comment: This does not change the behavior, thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the problem is this line:

```
w.OpenRead(s);
```

That's returning a `Stream` that you never close. Now you *could* just close it... but it would be better to use it, and not bother with the `DownloadFile` call:

```
using (Stream responseStream = w.OpenRead(s))
{
    string content = w.ResponseHeaders["Content-Disposition"];
    string filename = new ContentDisposition(content).FileName;
    using (Stream fileStream = File.Create(filename))
    {
        responseStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Downloaded " + filename);
}
```

Comment: This solved it, thank you very much! A quick question, I have noticed you frequently use `var`. Is there a specific reason for this, or just personal preference?

Comment: @GuyMontag: Personal preference, when it's obvious what the variable type is. In this case it would probably be better to use `Stream` to be honest - I was being lazy. Will edit.